# How can set $get in same page?

Tags: php

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="msg_id=<?php echo $id; ?>#example" class="link_comment">Comment</a>

<div id="example" class="modal" style="display: none; ">
Your message ID is :
<?php
echo $msg_id = $_GET['msg_id'];
?>
</div>
```

When I try to mouseover to Comment link, in status URL : I can see the msg_id value. But When I try to click the comment link (I using Jquery modal), it can't be show the value of the link.

So my question, how can I do that to make the value of msg_id show in Jquery modal.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look at the output source code! PHP runs on the server, once, before any JavaScript is run client-side. PHP does not run again on the client.

Comment: You need to use Javascript to make things change dynamically in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Since you open #example div with jquery Modal, it dosen't reload the page, hence $_GET is empty. 
You can achieve what your goal in at least 2 ways:

1. Use Ajax to load contents of #example div when link is clicked.

   ```
   <a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo $id; ?>#example" class="link_comment">Comment</a>

   <script type='text/javascript'>
   $('.link_comment').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var id = $(this).attr('href');
   $.get('givemycomments.php?id='+id, function(data) {
     $('#example').html(data);
   });
   });
   </script>
   ```
2. Load all possible contents when page is rendered with php. For example, you would have #example_1 , #example_2 divs. When link is clicked, get value of its ID, and fire Modal with correct div. **edit:** after writing example code i realized that if you have lots of comments, it can be quite heavy to load em all.

Comment: Can you give an example for this problem ?

Comment: There isn't a problem in this solution?